# Bonsai Ficus problem

Tags: bonsai

The leaves on my Ficus are dropping off at an alarming rate. The new leaves that had grown are going brown and are now dropping off. I have just come back from holiday after 10 days away. I watered it before I went and also when I got back but it looks as if it's dying. It's 12 years old and I don't want it to die. I keep it in the bathroom where the window is only 3 x 3 meters but I think the lighting is enough, or is it not? Please help if you can.

Comment: Can you give more info please, and a photo if  possible - such as one, how long have you had this plant, two, is it in a shallow bonsai pot, three, when did it start losing all its leaves?

Comment: Please add some pictures and whether you (or someone else) was watering it when you were on holiday.  Was the soil pretty dry when you returned from holiday?

Comment: @T pitt  Please send pictures and by now an update.  Ficus is one of those terribly fussy plants, change in temperature, funky drafts, change in location will cause a ficus to drop leaves.  But it could also spell a death knell.  Please send pictures!  10 days is TOO long for a Bonsai to go without water.  Too little soil to hold any reserves of water to last that long.  But please send a picture of it now, there might be a chance that you got home soon enough.  Bonsai need watering everyday at the most every other day...for established Bonsai.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be generalizing but often times it is water or soil problems. 
Based on that here is a good start to approaching the problem.

> Often times, when leaves turn brown and wilt due to under-watering,
>   those dead leaves will be crispy and dry. While with over-watering,
>   those leaves may still be soft and limp.  Over-watering can easily
>   lead to root rot of the plant.  Plants infected with root rot will
>   begin to brown in one section or side of the plant and the dieing off
>   of branches or parts of the plant will spread until the entire plant
>   is deceased.  Sometimes, a plant can look dead, but is still alive
>   even though it has lost all of its leaves.  Make sure to scratch the
>   surface of the plants stems with a knife or a pair of hand pruners. 
>   If you can still see green, then the plant is still alive and maybe it
>   was simply dropping leaves as a defense mechanism to the heat/drought.
>   Cutting back the plant and adding supplemental hand-watering will help
>   bring the plant back to life.
>
> The only sure-fire way to determine if you are over or under-watering is to routinely check your soil moisture.  You do this,
>   by sticking your finger 1-2" down into the surrounding soil.  If the
>   soil is moist than let it be.  Check again tomorrow.  If the soil is
>   dry, then it's time to water.  Water deeply and aim all water at the
>   roots, avoiding getting a lot of water on leaves and blooms.